# Data Extensioin of Contacts not stores in Publication List to a Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, email-studio, publicationlist

I Created a journey, First i drag Data extension, Then in next step i select a email Template here In delivery options available, So i Selected my Publication list. when i am sending an email To Subscribers, The subscribers information will not store in Publication list. How to solve this Issue. Please let me update.

Comment: there has to be some problem in your email interaction setup. can you paste some screenshots?

Comment: @pragyanshu kukreti, no Problems, i wrote a cloud page here i use When "MemberID" is null means subscriber information is not add to List/Publication List. So when i am sent email to Subscriber through the data will store in Publication List. But Here i am not removed the Cloud Page that is for another Process. How to Overcome this issue and Automatically Add MemberID value in List/PublicationList. how to do this one.